# Clojuratica setup in Windows

Tags: java

I have been trying to setup Clojuratica on Windows using instructions from Clojure Data Analysis Cookbook and http://drcabana.org/2012/10/23/installation-and-configuration-of-clojuratica/

Each time I run this code

```
java -cp ".\clojure-1.6.0\clojure-1.6.0.jar;.\Clojuratica-master\clojuratica.jar;
C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\9.0\SystemFiles\Links\JLink\JLink.jar;."
     clojure.main Clojure 1.6.0
```

I get the error

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Clojure (The system cannot find the file specified)

What am I doing wrong?